# Run hatch script from outside of project

Tags: hatch

Given a simple hatch project, what is a clean way of running it from outside of the project folder?

To be more concrete, say my project `myproject` has its root in `/home/me/projects/myproject/`, where the `pyproject.toml` and other files live. The `pyproject.toml` file contains a runnable script, as follows.

```ini
[project.scripts]
myrunnable = "myproject.main:main"
```

Say I am in my user folder, `/home/me/` and want to run `myrunnable`. I can do `cd "/home/me/projects/myproject/"` then `hatch run myrunnable`. But I find inelegant that I have to explicitly switch to the project folder before running it. I would prefer, if possible, to type something like `hatch --projectdir "/home/me/projects/myproject/" run myrunnable`.
I am aware that I can do `pushd "/home/me/projects/myproject/"; hatch run myrunnable; popd` (which I currently use) but is there some way more official and elegant?

I have tried `hatch --config "/home/me/projects/myproject/pyproject.toml" run myrunnable` but this fails because it tries to run `myrunnable` with a workdir of where I am currently (`/home/me/`) whereas `myrunnable` expects to be ran in the project root.

([This issue](https://github.com/pypa/hatch/issues/1166) is possibly related.)